# Set PropertyName using variable value

Tags: c#, reflection

I want to create a property of a class, and set the name of that property using a variable value.

E.g.

```
string resultValue = "stack"; 
MyClass myclass = new MyClass();
myclass.resultValue = "overflow";
```

Now here in this case, `stack` is the property name and `"overflow"` is the value of the `stack` property.

Please tell how is it possible.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Why are you trying to generate property?

Answer (score 3):

You could use [Reflection](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173183.aspx). For example:

```
string name = "stack";
string value = "overflow";
PropertyInfo pi = typeof(MyClass).GetProperty(name);
MyClass instance = new MyClass();
pi.SetValue(instance, value, null);
// at this stage instance.stack equals to "overflow"
```

This obviously assumes that `MyClass` has a public property stack with a public setter:

```
public class MyClass
{
    public string stack { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: What the difference between instance.stack = value?

Comment: The difference is that you don't have to know the name of the variable at compile-time.

Comment: Anyway, you need to check `pi != null` after getting it by name.

Comment: Strange.. question was about generating property, not about accessing by name.

Answer (score 1):

You should use Reflection for this

```
MyClass myclass = new MyClass();
Type type = typeof(MyClass);
PropertyInfo property = type.GetProperty("stack");
property.SetValue(myclass, "overflow", null);
```

Answer (score 0):

I think that the [Dynamic Source Code Generation and Compilation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/650ax5cx.aspx) section on MSDN should contain the information you need.

> The .NET Framework includes a mechanism called the Code Document
>   Object Model (CodeDOM) that enables developers of programs that emit
>   source code to generate source code in multiple programming languages
>   at run time, based on a single model that represents the code to
>   render.

I think that you could also get this done using [Reflection](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173183.aspx).

Answer (score 0):

I can't imagine why you want to generate property on your class, but consider other ways. E.g. using `Dictionary`:

```
class MyClass
{
    Dictionary<string, object> _values = new Dictionary<string, object>();

    public object this[string name]
    {
        get
        {
            if (!_values.ContainsKey(name))
                throw new ArgumentException(name);

            return _values[name];
        }

        set
        {
            if (!_values.ContainsKey(name))
            {
                _values.Add(name, value);
                return;
            }

            _values[name] = value;
        }
    }
}
```

Usage:

```
MyClass myClass = new MyClass();
myClass["stack"] = "overflow";
Console.WriteLine(myClass["stack"]);
```

Comment: You can skip the entire `if` clause in your `set` method because `_values[name] = value` adds the key if not present.

Comment: @ChrisWue Thanks, forgot that!

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you should take a look at [`DynamicObject`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.dynamic.dynamicobject.aspx). With this you can create properties at runtime by simply assigning a value. An example can also be found at the [MSDN article](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.dynamic.dynamicobject.aspx).

Answer (score 0):

Have at look at Mark Gravell's `FastMember`

It allows you to set properties in a dynamic manner.

```
// obj could be static or DLR 
var wrapped = ObjectAccessor.Create(obj); 
string propName = // something known only at runtime
```

[FastMember Blog Post](http://marcgravell.blogspot.com/2012/01/playing-with-your-member.html)

Answer (score -1):

As far as I know, is this not possible. You can try using a dictionary.

Comment: @hamad maybe Mariusz doesn't know about Reflection, then he didn't lie! :)

Comment: @Bazzz :) then one shouldn't reply without research and proper understanding